# How to set my price_range filers default lowers value to the CHEAPEST product's price from the collection?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-api

I created a double input field like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1xHh.png)

As you can see, the max price value is set to the most expensive product in the collection, however, my minimal value is set to 0... Is there a way to retreat the cheapest price from the collection?

Thank you for any potential help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can find a solution using custom code. Here a snippet which I used:

```js
var minFilterPrice = {{ filterMinPrice | divided_by: 100 | escape }};
var maxFilterPrice = {{ filterMaxPrice | divided_by: 100 | escape }};
```

```html
{% liquid assign filterMinPrice = 0 %}
{% liquid assign filterMaxPrice = 0 %}
{% for colProduct in collection.all_products %}
    {% liquid assign current_variant = colProduct.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
    {% liquid assign price = current_variant.price %}
    {% if filterMinPrice > price or filterMinPrice == 0 %} {% liquid assign filterMinPrice = price %} {% endif %}
    {% if filterMaxPrice < price or filterMaxPrice==0 %} {% liquid assign filterMaxPrice=price %} {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```